# Real Time Server vs Client to Client?

Tags: hosting, real-time, multiplayer

Hey all,
I'm an iPhone developer looking for a simple, but effective way to host multiplayer games. I've been able to create multiplayer games over local WIFI and Bluetooth, but connecting accross the internet has always been something I've wanted to do but never really been sure how.

My question is 2 fold: Is the performance difference between a hosted server and a client to client connection that much better to make a hosted server worth it?

And secondly, if that is true...is there any kind of hosting provider that won't charge hundreds a month? I currently have a $5/mo website plan which definitely doesn't allow that.

Thanks so much!
-Luke

Answer (score 0):

Your parameters are fairly vague, so I will give you my standard "Answer for a client who may know how to specify based on my broad picture" answer :
Up front, you cannot beat wifi speeds with internet speeds...  you can sometimes beat bluetooth with internet speeds.  :)

There are a multitude of online games which pass large amounts of state information to multiple clients, so yes, client<->server<->client communication is doable and very effective, performance-wise...

As for cost...  That depends on the amount of subscribers and the amount of data to be passed to them/received from them.